# How to do statistics on a cocoa application startup time?

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, cocoa

I have a cocoa application,I want to get the time from the application startup to it startup succeed.And then post the time to my server.Can someone give me some tips?

Comment: Use the [time profiler](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AnalysisTools/Reference/Instruments_User_Reference/TimeProfilerInstrument/TimeProfilerInstrument.html) of Instruments.

Comment: http://WhatHaveYouTried.com ?

Answer (score 2):

Define your starting point (e.g. application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) and ending point (e.g. viewDidLoad on the main view controller).  Create a class (with + messages) that has start and stop calls.  Once you get stop, post the time to your server (asynchronously of course).

Comment: Or just log that time to the Console.

Answer (score 2):

all this measuring wont take into account the runtime loading.
classes loading & !frameworks loading

it happens before your main and even instruments won't correctly profile it
although it will show that an amount of time passes between 'Run App' and main!

---

this load can have a considerable influence on your time especially when frameworks have been swapped out / you do a cold start

tried at WWDC WITH apple engineer and we could reproduce times ranging from 3s(normal time for my app) to 10(when we used safari before!)

Comment: I am sorry about my English.I really can't understand what this answer saying.

Comment: He is saying that, if you wanted the starting point to be when the user taps the App Icon, this approach may not be accurate.  After the user taps, there can be a significant delay before the first line of code in your app executes.